# flex datagrid: how to do a multiple selection programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, multipleselection

I have I datagrid, on which I want to select multiple rows on a other user interaction than the one intended by the Programm. I'm wondering, whether I can programmatically select some rows depending only on code?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the selectedIndices property to an array of indexes, or the selectedItems property to an array of items.

For example:

```
myDataGrid.selectedIndices = [1,2,5,8];
```